# InfluxDB and Grafana: comparing two databases with different timestamps on same graph panel

Tags: python, influxdb, grafana

So basically I would like to be able to view two different databases within the same Grafana graph panel. The issue is that InfluxDB is a time series database, so it is not possible to see the trend between two databases in the same graph panel unless they have similar timestamps. The workaround is creating two panels in Grafana and adding a delay to one, but this doesn't give a good representation as the graphs are not on the same panel so it is more difficult to see the differences. I am currently working on a script to copy the databases in question and alter the timestamps so that the two newly created databases look like the data was taken at the same time. I am wondering if anyone has any idea how to change the timestamp, and if so, what would be the best way to to do so with a large amount of data points? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is currently available via kapacitor, but assume a more elegant solution will be readily accomplished using FluxQL. 
Consuming the influxdb measurements into kapacitor will allow you to force equivalent time buckets and present the data once normalized.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm from my grafana instance that it's not possible to add a shift to one timeseries and not the other in one panel.

To change the timestamp, I'd just simply do it the obvious way. Load a few thousands of entries at a time to python, change the the timestamps and write it to a new measure (and indicate the shift in the measurement name).